# Is this question appropriate?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The question 
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/what-are-hot-research-topics-in-computer-vision-and-image-processing-for-phd-res doesn't seem appropriate on two accounts:

1. It is too vast as well as too vague to define "What is HOT" in DSP.
2. .. but more importantly it is also more of a concern to how to choose subject (which could be so for variety of reasons) but doesn't discuss actual DSP issues.

Should this be closed?

or DO we entertain such questions?